# Why learning with backward process is need in diffusion model despite knowing $q(x_{t-1}|x_t)$

Tags: deep-learning, diffusion-models

I recently learnt about the diffusion model in deep learning, can someone explain to me if we can induce noise to an input data and make it a gaussian like data, why can't we use the same process in reverse without training a network for denoising to deconstruct the gaussian data to the real image?

in other words $$q(x_{t-1}|x_t) q(x_t) = q(x_{t-1})q(x_{t}|x_{t-1})$$

we do have q(x_t) at the very last step which has become an gaussian through intoducing noise in iterative manner, and we know what conditional probabilities are, why we try to approximate $$q(x_{t-1}|x_t)$$, if it just a gaussian

Answer (score 1):

If you read the paper [High-Resolution Image Synthesis with Latent Diffusion Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.10752.pdf), you'll notice that the Gaussian is actually $q(x_{t-1}|x_t, x_0)$, whereas $q(x_{t-1}|x_t)$ is intractable. In this case, even if we know the appropriate distribution, we do not know $x_0$ in the denoising step (as that is ultimately what we are trying to predict) and hence we still have to approximate the posterior with some neural network approximation $p_{\theta}(x_{t-1}|x_t)$.